# I have an Excel data sheet that I would like to extract data from into a new sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel data sheet that I would like to extract data from into a new sheet. Find text and copy row. Can you please help with Excel formula?

Comment: Ummmmm, there are many many formulas that can help, but without data,expected outcome and/or a much better explanation it is hard to be more specific then: look into VLOOKUP,HLOOKUP, INDEX/MATCH...

Comment: MEL, could you please elaborate a bit more as outlined here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Maybe if you add some screenshots of what you currently have and what you want to achieve (a mockup) and some sample data. Yet, you should note that Excel formulas cannot actively copy data from one sheet to another. They will merely reflect the result of the formula within. I believe what you are looking for requires VBA.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get value from row in another sheet is very simple `=!SHEET:ROW`

> The WorkSheet is `Data` and the row I want to get value from this row `A1`
>
> Example >> Function = `=!Data:A1`

Comment: A1 is a cell reference, and a sheet name should be followed by `!`. 
Referring to a row `1:1`, column `A:A`. If you want to get the first row in a sheet named data, that would be `=Data!1:1`, that would return the value of the cell in row 1 and in the same column as the function.

Comment: Thanks for remembering me @ChristoferWeber I forget that.